# Create Revit file with Revit families using DA4R API

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Please can you advise on the below questions?

Read 2D entity data stored in CAD dwg/database such as WDH, Position etc and create 3D entity associate with Revit family using DA4R API on the cloud?
Assemble all the entities and generate and save revit file using DA4R API on the cloud?

Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the general idea, Yes, you can achieve that with Design Automation for Revit API, you can refer the [sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-revit.window.family.create) for creating Revit family. And we can talk more if any detail questions.

Comment: I have configured above sample for creating Revit family locally. When I debug the application from VS2017, workitem status is showing pending and timeQueued. Callback method is not firing to download the result. Pls share your thougts on this? Thanks.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem. Quick question, do we have any other alternate other than ngrok to fire callback method for downloading output file? Thanks.

Comment: I am interested why you want alternate for ngrok, is there any issue with ngrok? I am not expert on this area, I mainly use ngrok and it works pretty well for me, if you wan alternate, maybe you can check https://alternativeto.net/software/ngrok/

Comment: I agree that ngrok works pretty well.
    
In design automation api,   
using AutoCADIO PlotToPDF, files can be downloaded without using webhook callback and ngrok. Similar way can we do Revit files download (work item output) without using additional tools like ngrok? Thanks.

Comment: If my understand is correct, the answer is Yes, the output could be sent to your specified location after the workitem is successfully executed without the webhook callback...